# Loop through multiline string using awk scripting language

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a script it reads a string containing multiple lines. I need to loop through each line.

eg:

file `awktest`

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {

    LINES = "line1\nline2\nline3\n";

    while ( LINES ) {
        print line;
    }

    exit 1;
}
```

I've tried everything. This is my last resort. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Given your comment under [@RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586460/1745001) which precisely answers the question you asked above, your question obviously doesn't really state the problem you're trying to solve so [edit] it to really capture your issue with a good [mcve] if you'd like help. Otherwise there's really nothing we can do to help as we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk's `split` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
         LINES = "line1\nline2\nline3\n";
         n=split(LINES,a,"\n");
         for (i=1;i<n;i++) print a[i] 
     }'
```

The output:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

---

- `n=split(LINES,a,"\n")` - split the string `LINES` into array of chunks (`a`) by separator `\n`.
   `n` is the number of chunks
- `for (i=1;i<n;i++)` - iterating through all substrings

Comment: I am using something like this in a recursive function, but I am having a problem with arrays because the way awk works. But thanks.

Comment: `I am having a problem with arrays because the way awk works.` - not much help we can provide given that vague statement. Also, if you know how to write recursive functions I don't believe simply iterating over values in a string is really stumping you. Given that, I'm not sure what the point of your question is as it clearly doesn't describe your actual problem.

Comment: It's because awk variables don't have a local scope, it's all global. But don't worry, I will find a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: @Lawrence, awk operates its variables in local scope

Comment: Maybe the documentation is wrong? -> "Unlike in many languages, there is no way to make a variable local to a { … } block in awk"   https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the FS as `\n` and iterate over each field like this :

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\\\n"; OFS="\n";} {for(i=1; i<NF; i++){print $i} }' <<<"$LINES"
line1
line2
line3
```